# show hide jQuery showing all hidden tr

Tags: jquery, show

Hey guys I'm working with this forum, I want to hide the categories list, and when you click the th it will show the tr files. Which would be more topic discussions.

jQuery-

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".slidingDiv").hide(); 
$('.show_hide').click(function() { 
    $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
}); 
});

</script>
```

Then heres the html i am using.

```
<table rules="groups" class="highlight" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
  <left>    <th colspan="{catrow.tablehead.INC_SPAN}" nowrap="nowrap" width="100%" style="cursor:pointer;" class="secondarytitle show_hide">&nbsp;{catrow.tablehead.L_FORUM}&nbsp;</th></left>
</tr>
<!-- END tablehead -->
<!-- BEGIN cathead -->
<tr class="highlight">
    <!-- BEGIN inc -->
    <td class="{catrow.cathead.inc.INC_CLASS}" width="46"><img src="{SPACER}" height="0" width="46" /></td>
    <!-- END inc -->
    <td class="{catrow.cathead.CLASS_CAT}" colspan="{catrow.cathead.INC_SPAN}" width="100%">
        <h{catrow.cathead.LEVEL} class="hierarchy">
            <span class="cattitle">
                <a class="cattitle" title="{catrow.cathead.CAT_DESC}" href="{catrow.cathead.U_VIEWCAT}">{catrow.cathead.CAT_TITLE}</a>
            </span>
        </h{catrow.cathead.LEVEL}>
    </td>
    <td class="{catrow.cathead.CLASS_ROWPIC}" colspan="3" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<!-- END cathead -->
<!-- BEGIN forumrow -->
<tr class="slidingDiv">
    <!-- BEGIN inc -->
    <td class="{catrow.forumrow.inc.INC_CLASS}" width="46"><img src="{SPACER}" height="0" width="46" alt="." /></td>
    <!-- END inc -->
    <td class="{catrow.forumrow.INC_CLASS}" align="center" valign="middle">
        <img title="{catrow.forumrow.L_FORUM_FOLDER_ALT}" src="{catrow.forumrow.FORUM_FOLDER_IMG}" alt="{catrow.forumrow.L_FORUM_FOLDER_ALT}" />
    </td>
    <td class="row1 over" colspan="{catrow.forumrow.INC_SPAN}" valign="top" width="100%" height="50">
        <table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td><h{catrow.forumrow.LEVEL} class="hierarchy">
        <span class="forumlink">
```

It works except when I click it shows all the tr files. I want it to show one when that is clicked. Now I could label them

```
$('#category tr').click(function(){
```

except it uses a php file or something and auto generates when someone creates a new category so this would be impossible. I am working with a website to create forums. So I know i can use jQuery cannot access the php files. Can someone help me with the jQuery

Comment: Please post your rendered markup.

Comment: I think inside your click, something like `$(this).parents("tr").siblings(".slidingDiv").slideToggle()` would work. I assume you have little control over the html format itself.

Comment: Very little control, since alot of the stuff is committed through php variables. like some of the things I see are 'code'<h{catrow.forumrow.LEVEL}>
 for the heading size. where would i put the code you gave me? and undefined I posted my markups. the jQuery and the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
$(".slidingDiv").hide(); 

$('.show_hide').click(function() { 
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
});
```

The use of `this` will allow you to find the appropriate `.slideingDiv` in relation to the `.show_hide` which was clicked.

Comment: Oh man did you save me James! Only problem was it wasn't working at first, then i realized it wasn't closed all the way haha. just missing });

Answer (score 0):

"filter()" method can also be used to be applied against all the tr for complex tests

You can pass a filter function as argument ...

This function has to return a boolean which will determine if the current node has to be filtered or not

```
$('.show_hide').click(function() { 
    $('.slidingDiv').filter(function(i,e){
        // Ex: return whether the current tr has a particular descendant 
        return (!!$(this).find('span.foo').length);
    }).slideToggle();
});
```